# Access to the path is denied in C#

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0

I get an error

> {"Access to the path 'C:\storing_PAC_history_10_4_2016.xml' is
>   denied."}

when I execute the instruction of the following code `db.save(path)` which modify the file located at the given path   in an ASP.Net project.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                    XElement root = new XElement("Command");
                    root.Add(new XElement("StartDateTime", _commandsLog.StartDateTime.ToString()));
                    root.Add(new XElement("CommandName", _commandsLog.CommandName));
                    root.Add(new XElement("Output", _commandsLog.Output));
                    root.Add(new XElement("UserOutput", _commandsLog.UserOutput));
                    root.Add(new XElement("Status", _commandsLog.Status.ToString()));
                    root.Add(new XElement("EndDateTime", _commandsLog.EndDateTime.ToString()));
                    root.Add(new XElement("UserName", _commandsLog.UserName));
                    doc.Element("CommandsLogs").Add(root);
                    doc.Save(path);
```

`

Comment: Storing files in the root of the C: drive is not a good idea. A sub-directory of the directory your ASP.NET application is in would be a better idea. You can set IIS to not serve files from that directory if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging your application locally, you might ensure that you are running Visual Studio with Administrative Rights (i.e. `Right-click > Run as Administrator`) as the process spawned from it will likely not be able to access directories that would otherwise require it.

Otherwise, you can check the permissions on one of the following roles, which will vary depending on which version of IIS you are using and ensure that it has the proper permission(s) :

- `IIS_IUSRS`
- `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`
- `NETWORK_SERVICE`

As mentioned by others, **it's not a good idea to give root access to your applications**. If you are going to be using this in any kind of production manner (outside of a quick and dirty utility application running on your local machine), you should consider using a sub-directory from within your application and referencing the files from there (i.e. drop the files you are attempting to access in your Project and access them relative to your application).

Comment: Are you suggesting giving an ASP.NET application access to the root of the drive? As far as I understand, that is generally regarded as a bad idea.

Comment: No I wasn't meaning to advocate that. I was just indicating how OP might resolve the permissions issue, regardless of which directory he/she is attempting to access. As you mentioned, it's **not a good idea to provide root access to applications**, so using a child-directory within the application would be a much better idea.